# Laravel goes always in show()

Tags: php, laravel

I've in route a resource:

```
Route::resource('/p/{p_id}/certificate', 'CertificateController');
```

but in CertificateController it calls everytime show()
also when i search for url like

```
/p/#number/certificate/index
```

I've a class like this

```
class CertificateController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request, $p_id)
    {
    ...
    }
    public function show($p_id)
    {
    ...
    }
```

What's the problem?

Comment: when you locate to `/p/#number/certificate` url, also pointing your to `show()` ?

Comment: show us your routes on `php artisan route:list`

Answer (score 0):

When you use resource in Laravel the route 
    /p/{id} will automatically route to show method. That is how it was designed.

If you like to go to index try this route before yours,

```
Route::get('/p/{id}/certificate', 'CertificateController@index');
```

Comment: You forgot the `@method` after `CertificateController`

Comment: Thanks @EliasSoares !

Answer (score 0):

For redirect your url you can write particular method before resource route to drive you page like:

web.php

```
Route::get('/p/{number}/certificate/index','CertificateController@index');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can thank the docs for removing the 'nested resources' section.

This is how you deal with nested resources:

```
Route::resource('p.certificate', 'YourController');
// index -  p/{p}/certificate
// show  -  p/{p}/certificate/{certificate}
// edit  -  p/{p}/certificate/{certificate}/edit
// etc ...
```

If you would like to change the parameter names, you can do that easily via the 3rd argument to `Route::resource` which is the `options` array.

[Laravel Docs - 5.1 - Controllers - Restful - Nested Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-nested-resources)

[Laravel Docs - 5.4 - Controllers - Restful - Naming Resource Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters)